# create ListView of files after deleting and recreating of new files

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listactivity

I have a folder within the cache folder of my application. When I click on a sync button that calls the tasks. It then connects to a server and request the latest information. These are returned to me in json format. I then want to clear the folder of the contents of the files that are no longer in the returned json. In testing I delete all child objects of the folder and recreate them. I use an Async task to do this. But after, it doesn't always return all contents of the folder. I sometimes have to press sync twice.

The json format

```
    {
    "success" : "1",
    "forms" : [
        {
            "cid" : "3",
            "name" : "File 1",
            "fid" : "1"
        },
        {
            "cid" : "3",
            "name" : "File 2",
            "fid" : "2"
        },
        {
            "cid" : "3",
            "name" : "File 3",
            "fid" : "3"
        }
    ]
   }
```

The code below is the code I use to delete the files.

```
    String[] children = homeDir.list();
    for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
        new File(homeDir, children[i]).delete();
    }
```

This is what I use to get the json from the server

```
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(files, "GET", params);
```

Then I go through the json and create the file using the name as reference.

```
    JSONArray files = json.getJSONArray(TAG_FILES);

    for(int i = 0; i < files.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = files.getJSONObject(ii);
        String fileName = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

        createfile(fileName);
    }
```

Below is the code of the Async task that scans the HomeDir and then updates the ListAdapter with the files found.

```
    static File homeDir;
    File Userfolder = new File(cache + "/" + uid);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    private class UpdateList extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                try{

                    File directory = homeDir;

                    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
                    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                        String name = files[i].getName();

                        HashMap<String, String> files = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        files.put("name", name);
                        filesList.add(files);
                    }

                }catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
                try{
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                filesList,
                                R.layout.activity_main,
                                new String[] {"name"},
                                new int[]{R.id.fileName}
                        );
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Although the above code sometimes will only display a few items out of the list of files that are in the directory. When I check the directory the files are there. If I restart the process, all files will appear in the list. Do it again it repeats the problem of only showing a few files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you create and start the asynctask? As you have a runOnUiTread in onPostExecute which is normally not needed.

Comment: Is JSON files.length() equal to files.length in doInBackground? If you later test with only start the asynctask again, does it display all files then?

Comment: I had used runOnUiThread with a "private void" I copied from a tutorial a while ago. I then added it to this code as it was working. I call the Async task from the onCreate by calling new UpdateList().execute();

Comment: Both JSON files.length() and files.length are the same amount I have been testing with only 3 files available. Both have a result of 3 when I log the length of them. 

Is it the runOnUiThread which could be causing the issue?

Comment: In any case it is better that you do away with runOnUiThread. Did you try to only start the asynctask again later?

Comment: With starting just the async task after do you mean recall it at the end of the first async has finished?

Comment: Yes/No. Make for instance a button with which you only start the asynctask. Check also filesList.length. But first remove the runOnUiThread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use variable name files for two different objects:

```
File[] files
```

and

```
HashMap<String, String> files
```

That is not a good idea. Especially not because you use them both in the same loop.

Comment: I changed `File[] files` to `File[] filesList` 
Then I also removed the runOnUiThread and added a call to run the Async task again.
Which fixed my issue!
Thanks very much @greenapps

Comment: `added a call to run the Async task again.` ??????????? You are not calling it twice are you?

Comment: No not calling it twice I haven't created the loop. I meant to say I did what you suggesting and try only starting the asynctask later on